# Flexbox: justify-content ignored when row wraps and/or items consist of user inputs

Tags: css, flexbox

I have referenced this article on flexbox referred to me earlier today.  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

So far, flex has behaved as documented, except for in the following case where the box wraps its items and/or the items are inputs/selects.  Here is an example:

```css
#searchbar {
    border: solid 1px LightGray;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
}
.searchbar-control {
    display: inline !important;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div id="searchbar">
    <input type="text" class="searchbar-control" value="1">
    <input type="text" class="searchbar-control" value="2">
    <input type="text" class="searchbar-control" value="3">
    <input type="text" class="searchbar-control" value="4">
    <input type="text" class="searchbar-control" value="5">
    <input type="text" class="searchbar-control" value="6">
    <input type="text" class="searchbar-control" value="7">
    <input type="text" class="searchbar-control" value="8">
</div>
```

I expect the box to contain 2 controls per row. 1 & 2 on the first row, 3 & 4 on the second row, etc.  So far, so good.  However, I am finding that justify-content is ignored no matter what value is used.  In addition, flex-wrap (nowrap/wrap) are ignored.  It looks like align-items is also ignored.

I haven't had this issue on flex boxes with elements which are **not** user inputs.

I want to see 2 items per row, and I want there to be 3 equal-width spaces: left/middle/right.

Comment: The flex items are wrapping. `justify-content` is working. Can you elaborate on the problem? This is a demo with your code: https://jsfiddle.net/wnetuqa0/

Comment: @Michael_B, Thanks for checking.  I am puzzled that it works in the fiddle.  I posted a simplified version of my content.  In addition, I also have a mix of <selects>.  I wanted to see if the <selects> had anything to do with it, so I tried a few in the fiddle.  They align, but fiddle does not show the options or the value of the selected option.  https://jsfiddle.net/wnetuqa0/1/  I realize this is a new issue, but it makes me wonder since errors are occurring in each context.

Comment: The `<select>` elements are working. The `<option>` elements had no content in your demo. https://jsfiddle.net/wnetuqa0/2/

Comment: I see.  Well, my actual use seems no more complex than what we have shared, so I am at a loss for now and will have to spend some more time.  Fortunately, I have set the widths of the controls to 49%, and this gets me pretty darn close to the desired spacing.  Just wondering, but what happens if I come back to this question after a week or two?  Is it forever way down the list where it will never be seen?  Or if I post here again with a new comment, will it get bumped back up?

Comment: Post a comment here with my username and it should notify me. You can also post a new question with the updated details. You can also add a bounty to this question to attract attention.

Comment: @Michael_B, I looked in the inspector and noticed that, by default (from no act of mine), the flex had a text-align: left.  I went into the css and changed it to center.  It looks good, now.  I have no clue why this is the case.  The problem with not knowing why is that there can be a tendency to compound the error as I move ahead.  It also had a default of nowrap, yet the controls wrap.  I am glad they wrap, but this just doesn't seem right.

Comment: The default value of `text-align` is `left` ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align)). The default value of `flex-wrap` is `nowrap` ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap)). I can't tell you why items wrap in your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Widths for form elements (especially when mixing `<input>`s and `<select>`s) can be a bit fidgety. I've found that using the CSS style [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) can help standardize the widths:

```css
#searchbar {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border: solid 1px lightgray;
}
.searchbar-control {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div id="searchbar">
    <select class="searchbar-control">
        <option value="1" selected></option>
        <option value="2" selected></option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="searchbar-control" value="2">
    <input type="text" class="searchbar-control" value="3">
    <select class="searchbar-control">
        <option value="3" selected></option>
        <option value="4" selected></option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="searchbar-control" value="5">
    <input type="text" class="searchbar-control" value="6">
    <input type="text" class="searchbar-control" value="7">
    <input type="text" class="searchbar-control" value="8">
</div>
```